# I am stuck at presenting a full image on tapping the cell in UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, modalviewcontroller

I have a `UICollectionViewController` in my application and I wish to make the image in a particular cell of full size when the user taps on it.

Sorry for the hassle, as I am a beginner for iOS. As per my knowledge will it be presented in a new `View controller` and if yes/no, then how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post some code of what you've tried ?

Comment: SO is for getting help on specific programming issues. This is a question you should rather try some google research on first, and then post some code here along with a more specific question.

Comment: I understand, however as mentioned I am a beginner and needed help and hence I mentioned that I already have a collection view controller running but what I need is to view a full scale image once I tap on the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using storyboard, just add new ViewController to the scene and Ctrl-drag from the CollectionView cell to the ViewController to create segue. Choose modal if you want full screen.

In your CollectionViewController class, you need to pass the image reference to a property of the Detail ViewController. You need to use a public property, as the Outlet for the image is not set yet when the detailVC loads. After its instantiated, you just set the image to the Outlet to display it.

**MyCVC.m (subclass of UICollectionViewController)**

```
#import "MyCVC.h"
#import "DetailVC.h"

@interface MyCVC ()

@end

@implementation MyCVC

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"] && [segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[DetailVC class]]) {

        DetailVC *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailVC.image = sender.image; // or any other reference to the actual image to display
    }
}

@end
```

**DetailVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailVC : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image;

@end
```

**DetailVC.m**

```
#import "DetailVC.h"

@interface DetailVC ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation DetailVC

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.imageView.image = self.image;
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: Please answer the question as requested! You have just told him to navigate to the controller. If you have started explaining, atleast try to be more elaborative, clear and concise so that one gets an answer!

Comment: Thanks @Martin..shall try and get back

Comment: I will expand on this in a minute.

Comment: @MartinKoles Glad you came up with this! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I used modal to present the detail in the example, but you then need to handle the dismissal of the VC. If you use push, then the detail will have the navigation bar with a back button.

Comment: Also, you need to identify the segue in IB by clicking on it and setting Storyboard Segue->Identifier and then refer to it in prepareForSegue.