# IOS - Use Segue identifier in child method

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

This is probably a basic question - but I cant seem to find the answer to it in my searches!

I have a uiview setup which contains two input areas which are linked to a child modal view via separate segues.

this is my parent prepare for segue method -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goalInfo"])
    {
        [segue.destinationViewController setYourGoalViewController:self];


    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"longGoalInfo"])
    {
        [segue.destinationViewController setYourGoalViewController:self];
    }
}
```

basically i'd like to determine which segue had been used in the child view so I can apply the relevant filed updates and alter a title/description in the child view. - I basically need something very similar to

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goalInfo"])
```

but i'm not sure how to access this from teh child?  Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segue identifier is check on the source ViewController during its prepareForSegue: method. What you rather need is during prepare for segue is to set properties on the destination viewController and then when it loads, read these properties and set UI outlets.

Look at this example: [I am stuck at presenting a full image on tapping the cell in UICollectionViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373889/i-am-stuck-at-presenting-a-full-image-on-tapping-the-cell-in-uicollectionviewcon/22373982#22373982). It's about CollectionVC and its detailVC, but the principle is the same.

Comment: cheers - my issue with this method is that the child view will return data to the parent - and it needs to return the data to a different field depending on which segue has been used - so controlling everything from the parent wont work in my case.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I would then create a property on the child which will hold a reference to the parentVC. Then when you hit Save on child, you will update your properties on the parent using this reference. During your prepare for segue from parent to child, you will set this property using segue.sourceViewController property.

Comment: cool - yeah makes sense - as i have 2 segues - if i set a boolean property in the child to determine the segue and reference that to return the correct data that should do the trick - cheers for your help..

Comment: I'm still reading your original question as I was probably answering on something else :) But anyway, glad that you figured out.

Comment: Dancer, to solve the issue of setting different properties in the parent controller, pass a completion block from prepareForSegue to the child view controller and invoke that rather than setting a property on the parent directly.  It's a much cleaner interface anyway.